# Excel VBA AverageIF Zero

Tags: excel, vba, average

Hello I recently started to code in VBA and would like to implement the function 'AverageIF'.

[image: Data for my averageIf]

In the link you can see that in column B there are values after 00:00 and I would like to get the Average of the column B, starting with B2 through B32. 
Furthermore I would like to put the answer in B33.

The first code that i am working is seen here, this wil get the AverageIF:

```
noxGem = WorksheetFunction.averageif(Sheet2.Range("B" & beginRow & ":" & "B" & offsetCellNum2), ">0")
```

In the above code I assumed that Row B2 till Row B32 will be checked for values bigger than 0. I don't know if that is the correct notation, because I am getting an error :

My second code is seen here, this will put the averageIF in B33:

```
Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("B" & offsetCellNum).Value = noxGem
```

I think this code is working, because i have putted the data (B2:B32) with this code in a loop.

Do you guys maybe have any suggestion to what the problem would be?

Much appreciated!

**EDIT**

I have posted my whole code, My apologies!
The Error message = Error 424 Object Required

```
Sub averageif_1()

Dim noxValue As Double  'De waarde die je gaat nemen moet een decimaal 
getal worden. Single kan ook gebruikt worden
Dim noxCellNumm As String 'Je gaat in de kolom I zoeken per rij van 24 dus 
de waarde moet steeds veranderen I2 I3 I4 etc etc..
Dim x As Integer 'Dit geeft voor de 'GEM_Sheet0' aan, in welke rij de data 
wordt opgeslagen
counter = 0

offsetCellNum = 2
beginRow = 2
eindRow = 745

Dim noxGem As Double

While counter < 24

    Select Case counter
        Case Is = 0
            x = beginRow
            x2 = eindRow
            For i = x To x2 Step 24
                noxCellNumm = "I" & i
                noxValue = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range(noxCellNumm).Value
                'Debug.Print strValue
                Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("B" & offsetCellNum).Value = 
noxValue
                offsetCellNum = offsetCellNum + 1
            Next
            Debug.Print "00:00"
            offsetCellNum2 = offsetCellNum - 1
            noxGem = WorksheetFunction.averageif(Sheet2.Range("B" & 
            beginRow & ":" & "B" & offsetCellNum2), ">0")
            'noxGem = WorksheetFunction.averageif
            'noxGem = WorksheetFunction.averageif(Sheet2.Range("B2:B33"), 
            "=0")
            Debug.Print noxGem
            Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("B" & offsetCellNum).Value = noxGem
            counter = counter + 1
            offsetCellNum = 2
            beginRow = beginRow + 1


        Case Else
            counter = 100
    End Select
Wend

End Sub
```

Comment: What is the error message?  How do you expect us to copy your data into a worksheet for testing?  What is `offsetCellNum2`?

Comment: BTW, making a bunch of assumptions since you did not provide enough information to reproduce your error, your code works OK here.

Comment: Hello @RonRosenfeld, Thanks for reviewing my code and my apologies for not providing sufficient information and data! I have edited my post =)!

Comment: And what is the error?

Comment: @RonRosenfeld When running the error message is "Error 424 Object Required". When I click for more information the line where i have averageIF is highlighted in yellow.

Comment: Most likely you do not have a `Sheet2` in the active workbook.  And note that `Sheet2`, as used in your code line, is the `codename` and the worksheet name can be different.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code would be easier to debug if you declared all of your variables.
Put `Option Explicit` at the top of your code to force this.

To have this happen all the time, under Tools/Options select that option:

[image]

Had you done that you might find that `Sheet2.` in your `AverageIf` line is flagged as an undeclared variable, and that there is no worksheet with that **CodeName** (different from the WorksheetName) in your active workbook.

Comment: Thankyou!! You were right, "Sheet2" was the worksheet name and not the `codename`

Comment: With pleasure =)! Thanks again!